# auto fill input field in a registration if the person already exist in the database

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a registration form that requires the input of name, address, contact and email.

If the name already exists in the database the rest of the information should be automatically filled in using the information saved in the database before the clicking of the registration button.

Need help, how to automatically fill in the field without directing to another page.

Comment: This approach will open a way for third party to query contents of your users database and it can be considered as security hole. Normally you can check if unique identifier of the user (e.g. email) is already available and ask user if he wants to login or reset password.

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX call to an endpoint that checks if record with form-given informations exits. If so - return data so you can fill rest of the form